# Consume data from blockchain API

Tags: swift

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've been at it for an hour, I'm trying to print 1 or 2 lines from

https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/1/address/0x8f299f2908c9Cd71e723E7059Ac52eaea3638b2E/balances_v2/?&key=ckey_4eeea29a22c14701a9844f01151

but I get an error. I tried to debug it and it seems like my model and it's call is wrong, what's going on?

```
import SwiftUI

struct FetchingAPI: View {
    
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Fetching API")
            .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
    
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/1/address/0x8f299f2908c9Cd71e723E7059Ac52eaea3638b2E/balances_v2/?&key=ckey_4eeea29a22c14701a9844f01151") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                
                print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    // AFTER HERE THE DATA IS [] NON EXISTENT
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update our UI
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                    }
                    
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            } else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                semaphore.signal()
                return
            }
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
    
    struct Response: Codable {
        var results: [Result]
    }
    
    struct Result: Codable {
        var data: Int
        var address: String
        var quote_currency: String
    }
    
}
```

**EDIT: Adding error message after adding suggested try catch:**

I updated the code to be:

```
do {
    if let data = data {
        //  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        // we have good data – go back to the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // update our UI
            self.results = decodedResponse.results
        }
        
        // everything is good, so we can exit
        return
    }
    
} catch {
    print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    semaphore.signal()
    return
}
```

ERROR Message:

```
Unexpected error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "updatedAt", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"updatedAt\", intValue: nil) (\"updatedAt\").", underlyingError: nil)).
```

Comment: Error, what error? Please improve your question by adding relevant information like error messages and some sample json. When printing the error then don’t use localizedDescription but instead `print(error)` to get a more detailed error message

Comment: Hi, I added the error message, it seems like there is no data, is it in the decoding process?

Comment: You have not added any error message as far as I can see and when looking at your code I now see that you are using `try?` which means you are ignoring any possible error created from the decoding. Use `try` with a `do/catch`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you are right what I had added as log is that the data was empty. Now I implemented your suggested try catch with proper error message, does that help?

Comment: It doesn't say there is no data.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help when your declared Response and Result types look nothing like the JSON you claim to be receiving (in the link at the start of your question). It seems to me that you are misrepresenting something quite severely. Either you're lying about your code or you're lying about what the JSON is. My point is, though, that you are misreading the error; the `data` didn't vanish, the error is talking about the `"data"` parameter of the JSON.

Comment: @matt I thought at the beggining there was no data after decoding. I recreated the json manually and I see the same response, it's very likely because of the way I defined the model and how I'm calling it. What is the right approach for this?

Comment: @matt do I have to specify in the model all values that the api has?

Comment: You've already been told how to use https://app.quicktype.io/ to find out how to construct your decodable types. I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: That's the wrong solution... I bet you didn't even look at the API... Anyway I figured it out.. @matt

Comment: No, I didn't look at the API, I looked at the JSON in the link you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it without so much code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var address:String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Text("address: \(address)")
            Button(action: {
                makeApiRequest()
            }, label: {
                Text("make api request")
            })
        }
    }
    func makeApiRequest(){
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/1/address/0x8f299f2908c9Cd71e723E7059Ac52eaea3638b2E/balances_v2/?&key=ckey_4eeea29a22c14701a9844f01151")!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responce, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodeResponce = try? JSONDecoder().decode(apiResponce.self, from: data){
                    address = decodeResponce.data.address
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
        print(url)
    }
    
}

struct apiResponce: Codable {
    let data:apiData
    let error:Bool
}
struct apiData: Codable {
    let address:String
    let quote_currency:String
}
```